# How to vertically align the list-index of a list with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I needed to create a list with a **custom list-index** which is **vertically centered to the content** of the list items.

As I am using flex already I thought the easiest might be to give the list-item a `display:flex;` and style it. This works, but as soon, as the **list-item contains other elements it is messed up**. As you can **see in the example below**.

Whats the best way to vertically center the list-index?

**-- Updated Example --**

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

ol > li {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}

ol > li:before {
  color: red;
  content: attr(data-count)' ›';
  flex display: block;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  text-align: right;
  min-width: 24px;
  padding-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li data-count="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
  <li data-count="10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span>amet</span>, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
  <li data-count="999">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Well... how about big no-no, good ol' tables on CSS way? :) https://jsfiddle.net/vLk5Lxs4/

Comment: @sinisake Why big no-no? I think it's a good solution

Comment: @Oriol, thanks, but, since question is about flex... i've just left that fiddle as a suggestion... ;)

Comment: @sinisake OP did say _I thought `display: flex` would be a way_ ... and since your suggestion is a really good way to do this, post it as an answer and you have my vote

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution could be to use `display:table`, instead of flex, in this particular case.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
  display:table;
  border-spacing:0 20px;
}

ol > li {
  display:table-row;
  vertical-align:middle;     
}

ol > li:before {
  color: red;
  content: attr(data-count)' ›';
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
  text-align: right;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li data-count="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
  <li data-count="10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span>amet</span>, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
  <li data-count="999 99">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: I think I will go with that solution - as I don't have to add add wrappers to the existing markup.

Answer (score 3):

I think that the best option is to wrap all elements inside `li` in one other element and that should fix the problem.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
}
ul > li {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 20px;
  align-items: center;
}
ul > li:before {
  color: red;
  content: '›';
  flex display: block;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
  <li>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span>amet</span>, consectetur adipisicing elit</p>
  </li>
  <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks for that Idea - hoped there is a solution without the need of a extra wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a method with absolute positioning to keep the arrows vertically centered.

```css
ol {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  width: 200px;
}

ol > li {
  margin: 20px 0 0;
  padding-left: 36px;
  position: relative;
}

ol > li:before {
  color: red;
  content: attr(data-count)' ›';

  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1;
  
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%; /* vertically center */
  margin-top: -7px; /* and shift up based on 16px height */
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li data-count="1">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
  <li data-count="10">Lorem ipsum dolor sit <span>amet</span>, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
  <li data-count="999">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thats more or less exactly how I fixed it in the meantime. But this opens a new problem where I need to know the width of the list-index as it is defined by the margin of the list-item.

Comment: @StefanKunze How is that a new problem? I'm using the same `30px` width you had specified in your example for the gutter.

Comment: @StefanKunze I made a slight edit so the `30px` is only needed in one place again. Instead of `width` on the `:before` (like in your CSS), it's now padding on the `li`.

Comment: I changes the example from **unordered** to **ordered** so make clear that I don't know the width of the index. You couldn't know that - my fault sorry.

Comment: @StefanKunze Gotcha, now I know what you mean. Updated my demo accordingly, but it's more of the same. If you chose this as a viable solution, you'd just have to adjust the `padding` value with the knowledge of how long your list might end up.